# Negative binomial distribution — sum of two random variables with different success probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

Suppose $X, Y$ are independent random variables with $X\sim NB(r, p)$ and $Y\sim NB(s, q)$. From a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054048/negative-binomial-distribution-sum-of-two-random-variables), I understand that when the success probabilities are equal, $p = q$, then,
$$
X+Y \sim NB(r + s, p).
$$

**What is the distribution of $X+Y$ in cases when $p \neq q$?** If there is no analytical solution, I'd still be interested in an approximation.

Comment: Are they still independent? Because then I'd imagine $P(X+Y = k) = \sum_i P(X = k - Y)P(Y = i)$ but you'd have to take into account the fact that $X$ can have at most $r$ successes and $Y$ can have at most $s$ successes.

Comment: Yes, they are still independent. I'm well beyond my depth here...grateful for any help doing this (no matter how pedantic/spelled out)